# recyclerView.scrollToPosition doesn't fully show the recyclerView last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use  scrollToPosition(recycler.getAdapter().getItemCount() -1) in order to scroll my recyclerView to the last recyclerView item.

The problem is that all the recyclerView items are fully visible on screen except for the last item which is partially visible on the bottom of the screen. So, when I call scrollToPosition no scrolling occurs. How can I scroll the recyclerView to the last item so it will fully be display on the device screen?

Comment: kindly post the screen shot please.

Comment: Have you found solution? I am facing the same probelm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(count - 1, viewHeight)`